# Comparison between Western, Eastern and Islamic Philosophy

Tags: eastern-philosophy, islamic-philosophy

As a beginner in "**Philosophy**" ... I'd like to know the difference between the **Western**, **Eastern** and **Islamic** Philosophy in terms of Essence, Thought, Ideology, History, Purpose... etc. and the eminent philosophers of each philosophy who contributed and played a key role in their respective evolutions.

Comment: Most of Islamic philosophy falls in pretty much in the same tradition as Western Philosophy - both of them are continuations of Greek thought. Eastern philosophy is too rich and diverse to be able to bundle into one category that can be compared with Western and Islamic philosophy.

Comment: And a note on the nomenclature: there exist philosophies that aren't "Western" but are in the West - e.g. Native American philosophy.

Comment: I edited your question to remove meta text, we prefer to not include that in the body of the question.

Comment: I also have to put your question on hold because it seems too broad. Questions should be answerable in a few paragraphs. To compare three traditions on at least 5 topics and list key figures would take many more than a few. I would suggest that you focus on some topics only, and leave the key figures out.

Comment: @Keelan: Alexander kings comment seems a reasonable response, no?

Comment: @MoziburUllah not sure what you mean by 'reasonable'. Yes, it is relevant. He also says that eastern philosophy is too rich to be compared with western / Islamic philosophy. That seems to support 'too broad', right?

Comment: @Keelan: Well, relevant is a reasonable intepretation; thats one opinion; another is by [Garfield](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/11/opinion/if-philosophy-wont-diversify-lets-call-it-what-it-really-is.html?_r=0) published in the NYT in May this year. He make's some quite pointed remarks about how Eastern philosophy is seen in the Western Academy; one could, for example, usefully compare Greek atomism, with their Buddhist & Islamic  analogues or Advaita with Kant and Hegel.